# Different expires for different days in the current month

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My current Nginx config:

```
location / {
  expires 1d;
  add_header Cache-Control public;

  try_files $uri $uri.html @proxy;
}
```

But the `expires 1d;` part doesn't fit my needs. Actually the content is good till end of the current month. Or to make it easier till `00:01 am` of the 1st day of the next month. Actually it even doesn't have to be 100% accurate. If I lose a little bit of optimization in the last 1-3 days that is not a problem (thinking of the February 28th problem).

The solution I can realize is a cron job which updates the Nginx config once a day and reloads Nginx with a Bash script. But that doesn't feel right. I'd like to solve this problem within the Nginx config.

So I'm thinking about a set of if/else structures which fetches the current day of month and than sets a number.

The idea (not actually Nginx config code) would be:

```
if day_of_month = 1 
  expires 31d
end
if day_of_month = 2
  expires 30d
end
if day_of_month = 3
  expires 29d
end
...
```

I'm reading http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html but I'm not sure if something like this would work:

```
if current_month = 1 
  expires epoche "00:00:00 01-02-$current_year"
end
if current_month = 2 
  expires epoche "00:00:00 01-03-$current_year"
end
if current_month = 3 
  expires epoche "00:00:00 01-04-$current_year"
end
...
if current_month = 12 
  expires epoche "00:00:00 01-01-($current_year + 1)"
end
```

What is the best way to tackle this problem within the normal Nginx configuration? Can I use the current date in an if clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a normal Nginx configuration, you can implement your `if day_of_month` chain by using the `$time_iso8601` variable in a `map` directive. For simplicity, this answer ignores leap years, and sets a maximum expiry interval of 5 days, just to cut down the number of entries in the `map`.

```
map $time_iso8601 $expires {
    default                  5d;
    ~^....-(04|06|09|11)-27T 4d;
    ~^....-(04|06|09|11)-28T 3d;
    ~^....-(04|06|09|11)-29T 2d;
    ~^....-(04|06|09|11)-30T 1d;
    ~^....-02-25T            4d;
    ~^....-02-26T            3d;
    ~^....-02-27T            2d;
    ~^....-02-28T            1d;
    ~^....-..-28T            4d;
    ~^....-..-29T            3d;
    ~^....-..-30T            2d;
    ~^....-..-31T            1d;
}
server {
    ...
    expires $expires;
    ...
}
```

The regular expressions are evaluated in order, so place the least specific at the bottom of the list. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for more.

---

An optimum solution would be to generate an HTTP Expires header with the actual date and time when the document goes out of date, but the HTTP-date format is difficult to generate without a programming language.